# laravel symbolic link not working in hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I have a cpanel and it's a shared hosting. i cannot use ssh access. but i upload a laravel project and it works fine. my problem is i cannot active my symbolic link to my public/storage folder. i used this php file to make symlink to my folder. but it's not working. how can i solve this or any other way to make this happen.my localhost symlink is fine and working.

```
<?php

symlink('/home/testlk/testapp/storage/app/public', '/home/testlk/public_html/storage');

?>
```

Comment: Do you have `Options FollowSymLinks` on your apache configuration?

Comment: how to find that

Comment: Check if `.htaccess` is enabled and check if your project `.htaccess`  contains that line

Comment: this is my code in .htaccess

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   # enable symbolic links
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: You may have the `htaccess` disabled, look for your apache configuration and set `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None`

Comment: how to find apache configurations

Comment: With no ssh I can't help you further, check cpanel docs, I guess they will have the option to check it

Comment: I found the solution in this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210036/laravel-symlink-and-cpanel